# How to add an additional property for CustomUserStore in deployment.toml in WSO2 IS 5.9

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

My CustomUserStore is a primary user store.
In previous versions it was possible to just additional properties in user-mgt.xml like:

```
<UserStoreManager class="com.company.CustomUserStoreManager">
    ...
    <Property name="host">remotebox</Property>     // my two additional properties
    <Property name="port">5580</Property> 
</UserStoreManager>
```

But when I try to add them to deployment.toml like:

```
[user_store]
type = "database"
class = "com.company.CustomUserStoreManager"
host = "remotebox"
port = 5580
```

Then my properties are not added in the resulting user-mgt.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom properties to userstore as shown below from deployment.toml file.

```
[user_store]
type = "database"
class = "com.company.CustomUserStoreManager"

[user_store.properties]    
host = "remotebox"
port = "5580"
```